# Iterate through lists in values of all keys in a dictionary in parallel?

Tags: python

Hello I have a python dictionary that looks like this:

```
d = {'a': [1,2,3],
     'b': [3,4,5],
     'c':[6,7,8]}
```

Is there any way to iterate through this dictionary so that I am getting each item in all list value in all keys in order in parallel? Keep in mind I don't have `pandas` package available.

So for example:

```
loop 1 output: a:1,b:3,c:6
loop 2 output: a:2,b:4,c:7
loop 3 output: a:3,b:5,c:8
```

You can assume the list lengths are going to be the same for all keys in the dictionary.

Comment: Do you not care about the keys at all? If not, are you looking for `for x in zip(*d.values()): print(x)`?

Comment: @Brian that is a good point. I'd also like to get the keys if possible. I updated the original question to reflect that.

Comment: See [keys()](https://realpython.com/python-dicts/#dkeys) and [values()](https://realpython.com/python-dicts/#dvalues)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a one-liner

```
result = [dict(zip(d.keys(), v)) for v in zip(*d.values())]
```

Or if you want to split things up to make it a bit clearer

```
keys, values = d.keys(), list(zip(*d.values()))
result = [dict(zip(keys, v)) for v in values]
```